# File Not Found Exception - Can't see the issue

Tags: java, java-io, filenotfoundexception

I've tried directly linking using the entire path but that hasn't solved it either.

```
package eliza;

import java.io.*;

public class Eliza {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String inputDatabase = "src/eliza/inputDataBase.txt";
    String outputDatabase = "src/eliza/outputDataBase.txt";
    Reader database = new Reader();

    String[][] inputDB = database.Reader(inputDatabase);
    String[][] outputDB = database.Reader(outputDatabase);

}
}
```

Here is the reader class:

```
package eliza;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Reader {

public String[][] Reader(String name) throws IOException {
    int length = 0;
    String sizeLine;

    FileReader sizeReader = new FileReader(name);
    BufferedReader sizeBuffer = new BufferedReader(sizeReader);

    while((sizeLine = sizeBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
        length++;
    }

    String[][] database = new String[length][1];

    return (database);
}
}
```

Here's a photo of my directory. I even put these text files in the "eliza" root folder: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DVPi.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: A file reference would be relative to execution context of the program. Placing the files within the src folder makes the embedded resources, which is a different issue. Add System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath()); to the start of your program, which will tell "where" the program is being run from...

Comment: C:\Users\Tommy\Desktop\Eliza\src

That was the result. So I should be able to just use inputDataBase.txt then, shouldn't I?

Comment: I figured out the issue. I had the files in the eliza package folder in the source directory. I moved them to just src and problem solved. Is there a way to go about referencing a file in a packaged directory?

Comment: I'm worried about it running in the src directory, but yes, you "could" place it here. I assume your running in eclipse ...

Comment: Files dotted within the context of the application class path is generally known as embedded resources. These can be accessed by using something like getClass().getResource("..."). This returns a URL to the resource which you can access its InputStream to read its contents...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using an IDE, you need to give the complete canonical path. It should be

```
String inputDatabase = "C:\\Users\\Tommy\\Desktop\\Eliza\\src\\eliza\\inputDataBase.txt";
String outputDatabase = "C:\\Users\\Tommy\\Desktop\\Eliza\\src\\eliza\\outputDataBase.txt";
```

The IDE is probably executing the bytecode from its `bin` folder and cannot find the relative reference.

Comment: A better (and portable) solution would be to resolve the working directory ;)

Comment: It's interesting you say that because I have the files in the Eliza root directory too. I even copied them into every folder the IDE generated: build, dist, nbproject, src. 

What would be a method to make this portable so I don't have to specify the complete canonical path?

Edit: Didn't notice your comment about portability. Thank you.

Comment: @user2318481 Write a small script which includes all your jars and java files and compile it from the command line. Then run the main file from the root directory. All relative references will be resolved from that directory.

Answer (score 0):

give the exact path like

```
String inputDatabase = "c:/java/src/eliza/inputDataBase.txt";
```

Comment: "C://Users//Tommy//Desktop//Eliza//src//eliza//outputDataBase.txt"
"C://Users//Tommy//Desktop//Eliza//src//eliza//inputDataBase.txt"

I used that and it solved the problem. I need to make this portable though. Any advice how?

Comment: @user2318481 what is meant by portable?

Answer (score 0):

you have not given the correct path, Please  re check

try

```
{BASE_PATH}+ "Eliza/src/inputDataBase.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

The source directory tree isn't generally present during execution, so files that are required at runtime shouldn't be put there ... unless you're going to use them as resources, in which case their pathname is relative to the package root, and does not begin with 'src', and the data is accessed by a getResourceXXX() method, not via a FileInputStream.